# Displaying div tag in a textbox

Tags: html, sql

I am saving the below div tag into SQL DB:

```
String StrDiv = "<div STYLE=" + "''"+"font-family: " + lblPreviewPane.Font.Name + "; font-size: " + lblPreviewPane.Font.Size + "; color: " + ColorPicker1.Color + ""+"''" + ">" + lblPreviewPane.Text + "</div>";
```

The below query is used to update the message:

```
String sqlUpdate = "update iweb_messages set message='" + StrDiv + 
                "'where site_id ='" + mSiteID + "' and page_id ='" + ddlSitePage.SelectedValue + "'";
```

I retrieve the div from DB and display it in a **textbox** and a **label**.

In the **label**, the div tag is displayed as:   messagetoday21

But in the **textbox**, the div tag is displayed as:

```
<div STYLE='font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 18pt; color: #CC3399'>today21</div>
```

I need to display the text alone in the textbox also(same as displayed in the Label).

Kindly help me with some suggestions.

I use the below code to display the text from the DB in the textbx and label:

```
String sqlMsg = "select message from iweb_messages where site_id='" + mSiteID + "' and page_id='" + ddlSitePage.SelectedValue + "'";
    DataView dvMsg = dbLib.GetDateView(sqlMsg);
    if (dvMsg.Table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        txtOutputMessage.Text = dvMsg.Table.Rows[0]["message"].ToString();
        lblPreviewPane.Text = dvMsg.Table.Rows[0]["message"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying you are displaying it in a Label? Do you mean a span? It is not clear exactly what your problem is since it appears your div was built correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your "textbox" is a `textarea`?  If so, the behavior you're seeing is expected, because you're generating HTML that looks like this:

`<textarea><div STYLE='font-family.....></div></textarea>`

The content of a TEXTAREA is displayed without HTML rendering.  Whereas the label (assuming it's a `span` or another `div`) **will** render the HTML.

So, as a quick fix, you need to save `lblPreviewPane.Text` to your database in addition to the full `<div>`; then display the value of `lblPreviewPane.Text` in your text box instead of the `<div>`.

But I would also question the wisdom of storing the full `<div>` in the database.  If the font attributes **need** to be determined ahead of time, then I think you would be better off storing those attribute values in the table, then building the formatted `<div>` when it is being displayed.

Comment: The requirement of my project is to save and retrieve the div tag. I need a possible way to render the HTML content in the textbox same as the label. (The textbox is provided to make changes to the previously saved message and the label is to preview the changed message.)

Comment: Is my assumption about your textbox being a textarea correct?

Comment: Yes it is a text area.

Comment: You simply can't format text inside of a textarea.  If you want your users to be able to edit the text in a formatted manner, you will need to use a HTML WYSIWYG editor -- check out http://www.tinymce.com/